# Implementation of TR-BDF2 in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I want to implement TR-BDF2 adaptive-timestep version in matlab.
The C program is in https://math.la.asu.edu/~gardner/TRBDF2.c and there are a lot of online C++ version. But for matlab, I cannot find any except the constant-timestep version and thus have difficulty translating the C program to matlab version. 
Also, I hope to implement it in multivariable version in vector-matrix form. What should I pay attention to?

The essence of [adaptive timestepping](https://math.la.asu.edu/~gardner/TRBDF.pdf) is that I have to select each timestep inside a window:

[image]

In C program above it seems that this does it->The TR-BDF2 timestep selection is:

```
void compute_dt(GRID *grid, TIMESTEP *timestep, double F[], double F_mid[],
    double F_new[])
{
    int modes = grid->modes, i;
    double e_l; // = ||e_l||
    double dt = timestep->dt, dt_new;
    double dt_max = timestep->dt_max;
    double r, k = (-3.*sq(GAMMA)+4.*GAMMA-2.)/(12.*(2.-GAMMA));
    double EPSILON_REL = 1.e-6, EPSILON_ABS = 1.e-12;

    e_l = 0.;
    for (i = 0; i < modes; i++)
        e_l += fabs(2.*k*dt*(F[i]/GAMMA - F_mid[i]/(GAMMA*(1.-GAMMA)) +
            F_new[i]/(1.-GAMMA)));
    e_l /= modes;
    r = e_l/(EPSILON_REL*timestep->norm_u + EPSILON_ABS);
    if (DEBUG_dt) printf("TRBDF2 r = %g\n", r);

    if (r <= 2.) {
        timestep->REDO_STEP = NO;
        dt_new = dt/pow(r, 1./3.);
        dt = min(dt_new, 5.*dt);
    }
    else {
        timestep->REDO_STEP = YES;
        dt /= 2.;
        printf("WARNING: TRBDF2 r = %g > 2\n", r);
        printf("dt /= 2.; redoing timestep %d\n", timestep->step);
    }
    dt = min(dt, dt_max);

    timestep->dt = dt;
    timestep->FACTOR = dt/timestep->dt_euler;
}

void compute_first_dt(GRID *grid, TIMESTEP *timestep, double u[])
{
    int modes = grid->modes;
    double *D;

    D = (double *) alloc_vector(modes, DOUBLE);
    compute_D(grid, u, D);
    compute_dt_euler(grid, timestep, D);
    free((char *) D);
    timestep->dt = timestep->FACTOR*timestep->dt_euler;
    timestep->dt_min = timestep->MIN_FACTOR*timestep->dt_euler;
    timestep->dt_max = timestep->MAX_FACTOR*timestep->dt_euler;
}
```

Also, this part also do the comparison:

```
void select_dt(TIMESTEP *timestep)
{
    double t_max = timestep->t_max;

    timestep->LAST_STEP = NO;
    if (timestep->t+timestep->dt > t_max) {
        timestep->dt = t_max - timestep->t;
        timestep->t = t_max;
        timestep->FACTOR = timestep->dt/timestep->dt_euler;
        timestep->LAST_STEP = YES;
    }
    else timestep->t += timestep->dt;
}
```

But how can I do this in matlab? And does this scheme change in multivariable version of ode?

Comment: You are aware that the code you posted is for detecting the absolutely last iteration step and cutting the time step to advance exactly to the end of the integration interval? The error based step size adaptation happens elsewhere.

Comment: @LutzL  yes they are in `compute_dt`. Is this the same when the ode is multivariable and what matlab conversion detail I should pay attension to?

Comment: The original code is multi-variable, if you mean with that the dimension of the state vector. They are solving a discretized PDE problem.

Comment: @LutzL will this PDE also solve ODE of the form of `y = Ay`? What changes do I have to make?

Comment: The discretization of a partial differential equation usually results in such a structure, `y'=Ay+b(t,y)` where `b` is of higher degree in `y`. And y is the state vector resulting from the space discretization.

Comment: @LutzL What do you mean by y is the state vector resulting from the space discretization? When `y' = Ay` where y is the solution i want to obtain, can I just set `b=0`?

Comment: In your C source code at the top it says "Solves the nonlinear diffusion equation `du/dt = F = d/dx (D(u) du/dx)`". The boundary conditions at least will contribute constant terms in the discretization. And yes, if your differential equation has no constant term, then `b=0`.